# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android, view, parent

Guys I am getting an error and I am not sure how to solve it please help me.

Here is my code:

```
package com.appschool.www.projectphase1516;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.appschool.www.projectphase1516.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class AccountlistActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    LinearLayout horiz;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accountlist);
        horiz = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayouthere);
        Accountlistcreator();
        setContentView(horiz);
    }

    public void Accountlistcreator(){
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("details",1);
        int numofaccounts = sp.getInt("numofaccouns",0);
        horiz.removeAllViews();
        for(int i=0;i<=numofaccounts;i++) {
            TextView titleaccount = new TextView(this);
            titleaccount.setText(sp.getString("accountTitle" + i, ""));
            titleaccount.setTextSize(20);
            horiz.addView(titleaccount);
            Button seeaccount = new Button(this);
            seeaccount.setText("See Details");
            seeaccount.setId(i);
            seeaccount.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,100));
            seeaccount.setOnClickListener(this);
            horiz.addView(seeaccount); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.accountlist, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("details",1);
        int num = sp.getInt("numofaccouns",0);
        for(int x=0;x<=num;x++){
            if(view.getId()==x){
                Intent myaccount = new Intent(AccountlistActivity.this,MyaccountActivity.class);
                myaccount.putExtra("numbtn",x);
                startActivity(myaccount);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Process: com.appschool.www.projectphase1516, PID: 2751
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appschool.www.projectphase1516/com.appschool.www.projectphase1516.AccountlistActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3391)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:299)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1949)
            at com.appschool.www.projectphase1516.AccountlistActivity.onCreate(AccountlistActivity.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me out guys!

The code should create a specific number of buttons and textviews.

I am trying to remove and recreate all of them everytime I am going to that activity and am not sure why I keep getting an error :[

**EDIT:**

thanks it now runs but there is another problem

it doesnt create more than 1 textview and a button and i am not sure why

(i am pretty new to java development,so i dont know complex features like the comment above me ) i am just doing homework :P

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)

Comment: I recommend the following approach for creating the UI rather than hacking it together from code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
setContentView(horiz);
```

`horiz` is already a part of the activity's content view.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, you want to fill your layout with a lot of information by creating multiple textviews to show information, what you need is a list view and a custom list adapter, so you can get from your shared preferences info you will save in a list, and then pass it to the adapter so the adapter can build all the views you want and doing it better  and easier than your approach.

Answer (score 0):

First answer: `horiz` already has a parent (it's already part of the contentview which you set). Remove `setContentView(horiz)`

To answer your second question:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("details",1);
int numofaccounts = sp.getInt("numofaccouns",0);
```

Which means you get sharedpreferences (`details`) with entry `numofaccouns`. That one doesnt exist, however, because you never save it. You only get a non-existing entry, and if that one doesnt exist, you default it to `0`. The forloop is initialized like `for (int i = 0; i <= numofaccouns; i++)` which means you always hit index `i == 0`, because `numofaccouns` is always `0`

```
final String SHARED_PREFS = "details";
final String NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS = "numberOfAccounts";
final int NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT = 10;

int numberOfAccounts = 75;

//to save into sharedpreferences:
getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().put(NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS, numberOfAccounts).commit();

//to retrieve that value:
numberOfAccounts = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS, NUMBER_OF_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT);
```

saving all the accounts et cetera can be done in exactly the same manner as the example given above.